# How to make WebHint treat React-Intl <FormattedMessage> as proper <button> labels?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl, webhint

When using the [WebHint VSCode extension](https://webhint.io/docs/user-guide/extensions/vscode-webhint/) with React code, I often have this false positive issue:

> Buttons must have discernible text: Element has no title attribute
>
> webhint([axe/name-role-value](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.6/button-name?application%3DaxeAPI))

With JSX such as:

```
function MyButton({ labelId, onClick }) {
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
      <FormattedMessage id={labelId} />
    </button>
  );
}
```

Is there a way to make WebHint treat `<FormatedMessage>` as a proper label?

Answer (score 0):

Add a title attribute to the button and set it to the text that is displayed by the  component. This should prevent WebHint from barking at you. It provides a descriptive label to the button that can be read by screen readers.

```
function MyButton({ labelId, onClick }) {
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick} title={<FormattedMessage id={labelId} />}>
      <FormattedMessage id={labelId} />
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: The thing is that `<FormattedMessage />` resolves as text in the DOM when rendered. Also, you can't put JSX in the `title` attribute, it results in rendering: `<button title="[object Object]">Button</button>`